# Recommendation algorithm (and implementation) for finding similar items and users

Tags: algorithm, theory, data-mining, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have a database of about 700k users along with items they have watched/listened to/read/bought/etc.
I would like to build a recommendation engine that recommends new items based on what users with similar taste in things have enjoyed, as well as actually finding people the user might want to be friends with on a social network I'm building (similar to last.fm).

My requirements are as follows:

- Majority of the "users" in my database aren't actually users of my website. They have been data mined from third-party sources. However, when recommending users, I would like to limit the search to people who are members of my website (while still taking advantage of the bigger data set).
- I need to take multiple items into consideration. Not "people who like this one item you enjoyed...", but "people who like most of the items you enjoyed...".
- I need to compute similarities between users and show them when viewing their profiles (taste-o-meter).
- Some items are rated, others are not. Ratings are from 1-10, not boolean values. In most cases it would be possible to deduct a rating value from other stats if it's not present (e.g. if the user has favourited an item, but hasn't rated it, I could just assume a rating of 9).
- It has to interact with Python code in one way or another. Preferably, it should use a seperate (possibly NoSQL) database and expose an API to use in my web back-end. The project I'm making uses Pyramid and SQLAlchemy.
- I would like to take item genres into account.
- I would like to display similar items on item pages based on both its genre (possibly tags) and what users who enjoyed the item liked (like Amazon's "people who bought this item" and Last.fm artist pages). Items from different genres should still be shown, but have a lower similarity value.
- I would prefer a well-documented implementation of an algorithm with some examples.

Please don't give an answer like "use pysuggest or mahout", since those implement a plethora of algorithms and I'm looking for one that's most suitable for my data/use. I've been interested in Neo4j and how it all could be expressed as a graph of connections between users and items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually that is one of the sweetspots of a graph database like Neo4j.

So if your data model looks like this:

```
user -[:LIKE|:BOUGHT]-> item
```

You can easily get recommendations for an user with a cypher statement like this:

```
start user = node:users(id="doctorkohaku")
match user -[r:LIKE]->item<-[r2:LIKE]-other-[r3:LIKE]->rec_item
where r.stars > 2 and r2.stars > 2 and r3.stars > 2
return rec_item.name, count(*) as cnt, avg(r3.stars) as rating
order by rating desc, cnt desc limit 10
```

This can also be done using the Neo4j Core-API or the Traversal-API.

Neo4j has an [Python API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/python-embedded.html) that is also able to run cypher queries.

Disclaimer: I work for Neo4j

There are also some interesting articles by [Marko Rodriguez](http://markorodriguez.com/2011/09/22/a-graph-based-movie-recommender-engine/) about collaborative filtering.

Comment: for genres I recommend genres category nodes that items are connected to and you can take those into account in the match clause

Comment: Thats quite handy indeed , the link posted is storing the information in a graph-db as opposed to being a graph based approach to recommendation.

Comment: Thank you! I've done some more reading, had a look at the cypher cookbook in Neo4j documentation and it does exactly what I need it to do. I've decided to go with the graph database approach for my recommendation engine.

Answer (score 5):

To determine similarity between users you can run cosine or pearson similarity (Found in Mahout and everywhere on the net really!) across the user vector. So your data representation should look something like

```
 u1  [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
 u2  [35,24,3,4,5,6] 
 u1  [35,3,9,2,1,11]
```

In the point where you want to take multiple items into consideration you can use the above to determine how similar someones profiles are. The higher the correlation score the likelihood they have very similar items is. You can set a threshold so someone with .75 similarity has a similar set of items in their profile.

Where you are missing values you can of course make up your own values. I'd just keep them binary and try to blend the various different algorithms. That's called an ensemble.

Overall you are looking for something called item based collaborative filtering as the recommendation aspect of your set up and also used to identify similar items. It's a standard recommendation algorithm that does pretty much everything you've asked for.

When trying to find similar users you can perform some type of similarity metric across your user vectors.

Regarding Python, the book called programming in collective intelligence gives all their samples in python so go pick up a copy and read chapter 1.

Representing all of this as a graph will be somewhat problamatic as your undying representation is a [Bipartile Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). There are lots of recommendation approaches out there that use a graph based approach but its generally not the best performing approach.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to have a look at my open source project [Reco4j](http://www.reco4j.org). It is a graph-based recommendation engine that can be used on a graph database like yours in a very straigthforward way. We support as graph database neo4j. It is in an early version but very soon a more complete version will be available. In the meantime we are looking for some use case of our project, so please contact me so that we can see how we can collaborate.